# Cannot covert dictionary data to integer

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Hello I created an application using pandas to read an csv file and return the file removing all negative numbers in python that works, I am trying to implement this in a http api interface using flask and for some reason gives this type error and I cannot figure out why. I have tried converting  the array slice to int but it does not seem to help.
The error stems from this line of code within the for loop:

```
data[j][int(data[j]) < 0] = 0
```

Here is the error when i try to convert to int:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Here is the error when I try normally without converting:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import pandas as pd
import csv

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/data",methods=['GET','POST'])
def data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.form["csvfile"]
        data=[]

        with open(f) as file:
            csvfile = csv.reader(file)
            for i in csvfile:
                #csvfile[i] < 0 = 0
                #if int(i) < 0:
                    #i = 0
                data.append(i)
            data = pd.DataFrame(data)
            for j in data:
                data[j][int(data[j]) < 0] = 0

                #df.to_csv('modified1.csv',index=False)
        return render_template("data.html", data=data.to_html(index=False))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `int(data[j]) < 0` returns a boolean value. It cannot be used as an index.

Comment: _If_ OP gets it set up right, that's almost the right syntax for filtering a Pandas Series. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion because you're re-using the variable name `data` as both a list and a DataFrame, and as the name of the function.  I recommend you give them different names to help track the differences, perhaps `data_list`, `data_df`, and `data_func`. Reusing variable names makes debugging much harder, particularly if type (and scope) issues are a concern.

["Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) That means that when you append an element `i` to data in the for loop, what's getting added  is a list.  Your `data` is a list of lists, and your `data[i]` is a list of strings corresponding to one record (row) from the CSV.

Then you convert that list of records to a DataFrame with the same name (`data`), after which `data[j]` is a column: still a list of strings, but one in which the elements are different values within the column.

The error arises because there's no obvious way to interpret that "list of strings" as an integer. Your code asks Python to make that impossible conversion in the piece `int(data[j])`.

You might have better luck with the `pandas.read_csv()` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), rather than trying to build the DataFrame manually. If you still want to build it manually, you should probably have two nested loops: One to loop over records, and one to loop over the fields within each record.

Comment: I tried two nested for loops and got this error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That's not what your posted code shows. I don't know how you set up that inner loop, but you should not be iterating over integers.

Comment: for j in data:
                for t in j:
                    data[t][data[t] < 0] = 0

Comment: Try putting in some `print(type(<thing>))` bits - you're clearly having issues with variables not having the types you expect.

Comment: Yes this is the part I am having issues with and cannot seem to figure it out

Comment: `for j in data: for t in j: data[t][data[t] < 0]` is clearly a bad idea because - by construction - `t` is not an element of `data`. It's an element of `j`, and `j` is an element of `data`. Once again, your repeated use of the same label (`data`) is causing confusion. Fix that. Once again, you could also improve your understanding by inserting lines like `print(type(data))`, `print(type(j))`, and `print(type(t))`.